# How to test for nan's in an apply function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a simple `apply` function that I execute on some of the columns.  But, it keeps getting tripped up by `NaN` values in `pandas`.

```
input_data = np.array(
[
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(2)]+['']+['g'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(3)]+['g'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(3)]+['a'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(3)]+['b'],
[random.randint(0,9) for x in range(3)]+['b']
]
)

input_df = pd.DataFrame(data=input_data, columns=['B', 'C', 'D', 'label'])
```

I have a simple lambda like this:

```
input_df['D'].apply(lambda aCode: re.sub('\.', '', aCode) if not np.isnan(aCode) else aCode)
```

And it gets tripped up by the NaN values:

```
File "<pyshell#460>", line 1, in <lambda>
    input_df['D'].apply(lambda aCode: re.sub('\.', '', aCode) if not np.isnan(aCode) else aCode)
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

So, I tried just testing for nan values that Pandas adds:

```
np.isnan(input_df['D'].values[0])
np.isnan(input_df['D'].iloc[0])
```

Both get the same error.

I do not know how to test for nan values other than `np.isnan`.  Is there an easier way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: `input_df['D'].apply(lambda aCode: re.sub('\.', '', aCode) if pd.notnull(aCode) else aCode)` works but what are you trying to do?

Comment: For instance this does the same thing: `input_df['D'].str.replace('\.', '')`

Comment: You can use `math.isnan()` for testing for nan values.

Comment: `pd.notnull` works.  But am I the only one who is surprised that `np.isnan` does not work?  I thought that pandas nulls were built on `np nans`?

Comment: `np.isnan` doesn't understand empty strings that's why

Answer (score 12, accepted):

your code fails because your first entry is an empty string and `np.isnan` doesn't understand empty strings:

```
In [55]:
input_df['D'].iloc[0]

Out[55]:
''

In [56]:
np.isnan('')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-a9f139a0c5b8> in <module>()
----> 1 np.isnan('')

TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

`pd.notnull` does work:

```
In [57]:
import re
input_df['D'].apply(lambda aCode: re.sub('\.', '', aCode) if pd.notnull(aCode) else aCode)

Out[57]:
0     
1    3
2    3
3    0
4    3
Name: D, dtype: object
```

However, if you just want to replace something then just use `.str.replace`:

```
In [58]:
input_df['D'].str.replace('\.','')

Out[58]:
0     
1    3
2    3
3    0
4    3
Name: D, dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice, thank you.  I see that the string replace is much easier and more elegant, but I'm trying to understand `NaNs` better.  How do I create a `NaN` artificially?  I thought that `np.nan` was the way to do this, but pandas does not always convert that into a `NaN` in a dataframe/Series.  It also doesn't convert `''` to a `NaN` value.  How do I create `NaN` values in pandas?

Comment: Well `NaN` is a float type, there is no equivalent in string, you can have `NaN` in a str column this will make the column a mixed dtype. You'll have to decide what constitutes a missing value in string, an empty string would be fine but np doesn't recognise a blank/empty string the same way as it recognises `NaN` values

Comment: So, I suppose there really is no way to represent a `NaN` in a column that is of type `object`?  So, if I have a column of strings, and some of them are NaNs, I would have to convert the column values to floats before dropping the `NaN`s using `pd.DataFrame.dropna()`?  This seems a bit cumbersome....

Comment: You can have strings and float `NaN`, the column type will be come `object` but it's really mixed dtypes in that case `dropna` will work but it'll make some operations fail where the methods expect all `str` or all `floats`, really you should decide on what should be a missing value so an empty string would be fine in which case you can detect using `df['col'] == ''`